# How to add code block for code snippets for in the data displays in the react hooks page

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, contentful

I am displaying blog contents from `contentful` in my react hooks website. Now the full description of blog is received in `post.description`. I would like to display `code snippets, json data` received in post.description as `code  block`. Also would like to add the head lines to h1 or h2 tag. How can we identify the code block from description field ? Now it just displays the text in the page ( please refer the screen shot added )

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import MD from "react-markdown";
import { useSinglePost } from "../custom-hooks";
import Moment from 'moment';



export default function SinglePost() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [post, isLoading] = useSinglePost(id);

  const renderPost = () => {
    if (isLoading) return ( <div> <p className="noSearchData">Loading...</p> </div>);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="main_intro">
          <h3 className="blog_title">{post.title}</h3>
          <small className="blog_date">{Moment(post.createdAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')}</small>
          <pre className="blog_main_desc"><code>{post.description}</code></pre>
          <img
            className="blog_img"
            src={post.image.fields.file.url}
            alt={post.title}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="post__body">
          <MD source={post.body} />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <Link className="post__back" to="/">
        {"< Back"}
      </Link>

      {renderPost()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To include the code snippet as a block of code in ReactJs you could use a syntax highlighter like react-syntax-highlighter

install npm react-syntax-highlighter --save

And then in your code import the highlighter:

```
import SyntaxHighLighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { dracula } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/hljs';

<SyntaxHighLighter language="javascript" style={dracula}>
{
    "class HelloMessage extends React.Component {\n render() {\n return ( \n <div>\nHello {this.props.name}\n</div>\n);\n }\n}\n\nReactDOM.render(\n<HelloMessage name='Taylor' />,\ndocument.getElementById('hello-example')\n);"
  }
</SyntaxHighLighter>
```

Comment: I have post.description contains the description and code snippets, will that automatically identify the code. Will try soon and reply

Comment: I have tried, but I am getting following Error: Expected `string` for value, got `[object Object]`   I have added SyntaxHighLighter as following...  ``<SyntaxHighLighter language="javascript" style={dracula}>
              <pre className="post__intro__desc"><code>{post.description}</code></pre>
              </SyntaxHighLighter>``

Comment: I am using React hooks in my example and getting the blog data in `post`, so could you please explain how to use `SyntaxHighLighter` as per my question above ?

Comment: Adding the <pre> and <code> tags is causing the error. Could you please try 
<SyntaxHighLighter language="javascript" style={dracula}>           
      {post.description}
</SyntaxHighLighter>

Comment: Thank you very much, now its getting better. I have removed the pre and code tags as suggested. The result received-  now it is adding everything thing as highlighted ..Please refer the new screenshot added to the question above. Any suggestions

Comment: It looks great.. Is this the output you were looking for ? Do you still want any changes ?

Comment: I would need to highlight just the code part alone and leave the text as it is..